# Are YBCO or BSCCO rods able to superconduct at full $J_{c}$?

Tags: electric-current, material-science, superconductivity

My understanding of the state of the art for superconducting cables is that ceramic powder is manufactured, then it's packed very tightly into a silver tube. I'm not sure how this is supposed to solve the problem of aligning the crystal axes, but maybe the tube process is for [BSCCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth_strontium_calcium_copper_oxide) only and BSCCO doesn't need to be aligned and [YBCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttrium_barium_copper_oxide) uses a different process.

In any case, if the mechanical flexibility of a cable isn't needed, why not just sinter a bunch of the powder together to make a rigid superconducting rod and spare the expense of the silver and the packaging?

Comment: The calcination:
The purpose of this operation is to transform the mixture of powders into a material decomposition and well defined crystalline structure. During this reaction, there is a release of carbon dioxide, and possibly some water vapour. The process calcination of BaCO3 can be carried out in a muffle furnace for 12 hours at a temperature of 950°C with a heating rate of 10°C/min. The temperature at which the samples essentially causes the decomposition of barium carbonates according to
the equation: BaCO3 → BaO + CO2

Answer (score 0):

Sintering temperature may affect the microscopic, hence superconducting, properties of a material, especially a delicately structured one like a HTS. See [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-2048/3/4/009/pdf) for an example.